# Hiding section titles when the section is empty

Tags: macros, sectioning, conditionals, etoolbox

I have created a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\showsection}[2]{
    \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{\section{#1} #2}
}
```

It should be used like this in the document:

```
\showsection{Books}{
    Do you know any good books?
}
```

If `#2` is empty, as in this case below, the section title to not be shown:

```
\showsection{Books}{

}
```

Unfortunately, with some macros inside, which should sometimes appear blank, somehow something is getting through. Perhaps it is an extra space? No text is visible. I have put `%` after every line of the macros which I placed inside. How can I get the section titles to disappear in this case?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of `etoolbox`. There are also described the commands `\ifblank` and `\ifstrempty`. Another mehtod is using the pacakge `xparse`.

Comment: Please mention important packages in the text, not just as tags. It is always good to post a add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem exactly and lets people test their solutions easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have an end-of-line character after the opening `{` which causes a space. 
It might be better to check if the argument is a single space instead of being empty. You can add one space to the argument yourself to make sure the test is true for a real empty content.

Also you should add `%` after any `{` or `}` at the end of a line inside the macro definition.

```
\newcommand{\showsection}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\section{#1} #2}%
}
```

Comment: I posted an advanced solution for the follow-up question [Macros for hiding empty sections do not work properly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54309/2975) which is also interesting for this question.