# Macros for hiding empty sections do not work properly

Tags: macros, sectioning, conditionals

In an attempt to make it possible to outline much of my document by adding new parts to it, but without making parts that I have not written anything on show up in the compiled document, I have defined five macros based on a macro from [Hiding section titles when the section is empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38775/hiding-section-titles-when-the-section-is-empty):

```
\newcommand{\showpart}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\part{#1} #2}%
}
\newcommand{\showchapter}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\chapter{#1} #2}%
}
\newcommand{\showsection}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\section{#1} #2}%
}
\newcommand{\showsubsection}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\subsection{#1} #2}%
}
\newcommand{\showsubsubsection}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{}{\subsubsection{#1} #2}%
}
```

and now I'm using them all over my source file instead of the normal `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. I've also added `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in the preamble in order to get the `ifstrequal` macro. However, all the parts that I have not started to write anything on still show up in the compiled document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The commands work for me. You probably have some extra spaces somewhere. Can you show us how you use the macros?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue you seem to have is that you have empty lines in the second argument of you `\showxxxx` macros. This empty lines cause a paragraph break, i.e. a `\par` is added. This means you have to test for three different things: argument is completely empty, argument is a space, argument is a space plus `\par`. You can do this using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showsection}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{#2}%
    \def\@tempb{ \par}%
    \ifcase0%
       \ifx\@tempa\@empty 1\else
       \ifx\@tempa\space  1\else
       \ifx\@tempa\@tempb 1\fi\fi\fi
    \relax
       \endgroup
       \section{#1} #2%
    \else
       \endgroup
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showsection{test1}{
    Some text
}

\showsection{test2}{}

\showsection{test3}{
}

\showsection{test4}{

}

\end{document}
```

If you need this for multiple different sectioning commands, I would turn this into a general macro and not copy the code for every command.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showsectioning}[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{#3}%
    \def\@tempb{ \par}%
    \ifcase0%
       \ifx\@tempa\@empty 1\else
       \ifx\@tempa\space  1\else
       \ifx\@tempa\@tempb 1\fi\fi\fi
    \relax
       \endgroup
       #1{#2} #3%
    \else
       \endgroup
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\showsection{\showsectioning\section}
\newcommand\showsubsection{\showsectioning\subsection}
\newcommand\showsubsubsection{\showsectioning\subsubsection}
\newcommand\showchapter{\showsectioning\chapter}
\newcommand\showpart{\showsectioning\part}
```

---

### Alternative better solution

As you want to also ignore higher sectioning commands with only empty lower sectioning commands the above solution is not reasonable. (If you would have posted a normal usage example it would have been better.) You would have to check for a lot of combinations. I would recommend a different approach.
Instead of reading the whole (sub-..)section as macro argument, which is anyway very inefficient, you could have the `\show...` macros look ahead and check if there is anything else except `\par` or another `\show...` macro. If this macro is a lower sectioning macro, remember the current one using a buffer and repeat as long you either find some content or a higher `\show...` macro.
Programming something like this within the power of TeX, but an advanced topic.

Here my suggested solution inclusive example/test code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\showpart}{%
    \showsectioning{1}\part
}
\newcommand{\showchapter}{%
    \showsectioning{2}\chapter
}
\newcommand{\showsection}{%
    \showsectioning{3}\section
}
\newcommand{\showsubsection}{%
    \showsectioning{4}\subsection
}
\newcommand{\showsubsubsection}{%
    \showsectioning{5}\subsubsection
}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@1\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@2\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@3\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@4\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@5\endcsname\@empty
\chardef\showsectioning@highestlevel=0\relax
\newcommand{\showsectioning}[3]{%
    \@ifnextchar\par{%
        \@firstoftwo{\showsectioning{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    }{%
        \@showsectioning{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}
% Own macro for efficiency
% The next token is in \@let@token
\newcommand{\@showsectioning}[3]{%
        % Store highest level
        \ifnum\showsectioning@highestlevel=0
            \chardef\showsectioning@highestlevel=#1\relax
        \fi
        % Store number of next sectioning macro (0 = no sectioning macro)
        \chardef\showsectioning@number=0%
            \ifx\@let@token\showpart 1\else
            \ifx\@let@token\showchapter 2\else
            \ifx\@let@token\showsection 3\else
            \ifx\@let@token\showsubsection 4\else
            \ifx\@let@token\showsubsubsection 5\fi
            \fi\fi\fi\fi\relax
        \ifcase0%
            \ifnum#1<\showsectioning@number 1\else
            \ifnum\showsectioning@number>\showsectioning@highestlevel 2\else
            \ifnum\showsectioning@number>0 3\else
            \ifx\@let@token\end 3\fi
            \fi\fi\fi
        \relax% case 0
            % Some content found
            % Pasting and clearing all buffers
            \@tempcnta=\showsectioning@highestlevel
            \loop
                \csname showsectioning@buffer@\number\@tempcnta\endcsname
                \global\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@\number\@tempcnta\endcsname\@empty
                \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
                \ifnum\@tempcnta<6
            \repeat
            #2{#3}%
        \or% case 1
            % Lower sectioning command found, buffering current level
            \global\@namedef{showsectioning@buffer@#1}{#2{#3}}%
        \or% case 2
            % Higher sectioning command found, but still a lower one than the highest level
            % Clearing all buffers up to this level
            \@tempcnta=\showsectioning@number
            \loop
                \global\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@\number\@tempcnta\endcsname\@empty
                \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
                \ifnum\@tempcnta<6
            \repeat
        \else% case 3
            % Some end delimiter found (\end, \show... command of higher level)
            % Therefore no content, clearing all buffers
            \@tempcnta=\showsectioning@highestlevel
            \loop
                \global\expandafter\let\csname showsectioning@buffer@\number\@tempcnta\endcsname\@empty
                \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
                \ifnum\@tempcnta<6
            \repeat
        \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showsection{Not empty}
test
\showsection{empty}



\showsection{Not empty again}

Hello

\showsection{With empty subsection}

\showsubsection{empty subsection}

\showsection{With non empty subsection}

\showsubsection{Non empty subsection}
Not empty


\showsection{With empty subsection and empty subsubsection}

\showsubsection{empty subsection}

\showsubsubsection{empty subsubsection}

\showsection{Not empty, but with empty subsection}
Stuff

\showsubsection{empty subsection}

\showsection{With \texttt{\string\empty}}
\empty

\showsection{With \texttt{\string\relax}}
\relax


\showsection{Multiple levels 1}
\showsubsection{Multiple levels 1a}
\showsubsection{Multiple levels 1b}
\showsubsubsection{Multiple levels 1bI}
\showsubsubsection{Multiple levels 1bII}
\showsubsection{Multiple levels 1c}
    test

\showsection{trailing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm new to LaTeX so I didn't fully understand everything you did. Why do you use `\makeatletter` in this case? Isn't it possible to just define `tempa` and `tempb` without the `@` symbol?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: The `\makeatletter` enables `@` in macro names. You can use `\tempa` and `\tempb` as well, but `\@tempa` and `\@tempb` already exists and are of often used. Then you need `\@empty` which however also exists as `\empty`, so you really don't need `\makeatletter` if you don't want to use it.

Comment: Hm, this macro doesn't seem to work if the section has an empty subsection, for example: `\showsection{Section name}{ \showsubsection{Subsection name}{ } }`

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: Ah, I see. No it doesn't work when there is extra content in it. This whole concept is rather unusual. You won't be able to test for all possible scenarios and combinations. A different approach I posted in my update is better suited.

Comment: I tried you implementation but it still doesn't seem to work. I may have implemented it incorrectly, though. However, I think I will remove the macros and just use the normal commands, bescause now my preamble looks like a total mess... :P Thanks for the help, I may create a sty file for the macros and try to make it work later on.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: I tested the macros and they should work. I agree on putting them into an extra file. If you have issues just post a minimal example which shows the error/misbehavior you get.